# Using length or weight as quantity

Tags: product, inventory

Does magento offer any way to sell products by weight/length such as in the case of selling Apple,Meat...etc. I have to sell them by weight. I have 1000kg of apples in my stock. Customers should be able to order any weight from my store (1.5 kg, .5 Kg, 3kg ...etc), price will be calculated as per weight. Suppose a customer buys 3.5 kg of apples the stock after selling should be 996.5 kg.

Can the same can be done with length also ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is official setting for this but let's say you create a product **Apples**. The price of this product is the price per kilogram. Now if you go to the `stock` tab of the product you can edit `Qty Uses Decimals` and set it to `Yes`.

If you have a 1000 kilos of apples set the stock to 1000.

In the frontend change the label of the Quantity field and any other place the label `Quantity` is used to *Kilogram* and you're basically done.

Although theoretically Magento still sees quantity as an item, on the frontend it would look like the user is ordering per kilo.